# How to show that $\left|\int_0^x \frac{\sin u} u \, du\right|$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> How to show that $\left|\int_0^x \frac{\sin u} u \, du\right|$ is bounded?

Is it because $\left|\int_0^x \frac{\sin u} u \, du\right|\leq \left|\cos1-\int_0^x \frac{\cos u}{u^2} \, du\right|$, which is finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is well known, $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x \frac{\sin u }{u } \, du  = \frac{\pi}{2}$  which proves boundedness, but without using this fact we can argue as follows.

Fixing $a > 0$, by [Bonnet's mean value theorem for integrals](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bonnet_theorem)
 there exists $\xi_x \in (a,x)$ such that for all $x > a$,

$$\left|\int_a^x \frac{\sin u}{u}\, du\right| = \left|\frac{1}{a}\int_a^{\xi_x} \sin u\, du\right| = \frac{|\cos \xi_x - \cos  a|}{a} \leqslant \frac{2}{a},$$

and $\int_0^a \frac{\sin u }{u} \, du$ is finite.

Answer (score -1):

*Hint.* Differentiate the argument of $|\cdot|$ with respect to $x.$ Then show that the argument has global extema.

Answer (score -2):

- Prove that $\sin(x) \leq x$ for $x \geq 0$
- For $x < 0$, note that the integrand is even.

Comment: Those facts are not enough to prove that $|\int \sin(u)/udu|<K$: $|\int \frac{1}{|x|}|$ satisfies your hypothesis and yet $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{|x|}=\infty$

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I misread the question.